# Managed Property with "Allow multiple values"

Tags: managed-metadata, managed-property

Anyone out there who could help me with returning the search query based on the field on which I have set Allow multiple values. Like lately I have figured that If I have a managed property for instance "Field1"

Now if I use it in my query text like Field1: it returns me the result set and it kinda like work as a WHERE clause.

But if i try to do the same with a multi valued managed property it doesnt return anything, in fact it gives me an error. Is there any thing that could be done to use a multi valued managed property as a filter condition using API.

I am using the search API on the client side to request the results. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.